# Which .NET library / wrapper do you recommend for sniffing packets?

Tags: .net, packet-capture, winpcap, sniffing

As far as I understand all sniffing libraries in .NET just a wrapper around WinpCap, which is OK. If you know any other better option please write as answer.

Have you used any of them? Which one is the best according to your experience?

*I'm only looking for libraries which have commercial friendly licenses, Also commercial libraries are OK as soon as they got a decent price tag*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [Microsoft Network Monitor](https://connect.microsoft.com/site/sitehome.aspx?SiteID=216)? It's free, supported, and has an API you can use, in addition to a set of parsers available on [CodePlex](http://www.CodePlex.com/NMParsers).

Comment: Apparently redistribution  is not allowed for MS Network Monitor, which doesn't work for me, but thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Slough: I hadn't realized that. OTOH, you might ask MS on their blog if there's a way around that for your purposed. Maybe if your installer were to prompt the user to accept the MS EULA, MS would allow you to include the binaries or their installer. Ask, and find out.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I'll look around a little bit more. The problem is that also I didn't see any sample application using it which might be a problem and turn out to be an immature or quite complicated stuff. Played with some Winpcap stuff, they are quite straight forward.

Comment: @Slough: Good luck, but FYI: Network Monitor has been around for a while, improving with every release. See https://connect.microsoft.com/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?SiteID=216&DownloadID=4547, about version 3.0, in Nov 2006. Agree on samples, but do ask.

Comment: _Network Monitor is the archived version protocol analyzer and is no longer under development. Microsoft Message Analyzer is the replacement for Network Monitor_  [Microsoft Message Analyzer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44226)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SharpPcap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharppcap/) (C# wrapper and packet parser or WinPcap).

Both WinPcap and SharpPcap are developed under licences that allow redistribution.